# Multiple Nested IF statement in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck in excel trying to get the output as shown. I have a workbook with two excel sheets.I am trying to get product price on sheet 2, but for that some rules need to be followed:

1. If Type is SLP for a SKU on sheet1 then on sheet2 same SKU having a cross reference and having status_type Active should have Product Price from sheet1 and SLP(status_Type) for same SKU should have SLP value from sheet1.
2. If type is PD for a SKU on sheet 1 then on sheet 2 same SKU having a cross reference and having status_type Active then have PD from sheet1 for that SKU and SLP value . The shown output example makes it more clear. I tried by IF statement but didn't have any success. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

SHEET1:

```
SKU Type    Product Price   PD     SLP
A   SLP         14.99        0    11.99
B   PD          16.99      15.99    0
```

SHEET2:

```
SKU   Cross_Reference   Status_Type  Product Price
A        A               Active           ?
A        A1              Active           ?
A       0-A               SLP             ?
A       0-B               SLP             ?
A       0-C               SLP             ?
B        B              Active            ?
B        B1             Active            ?
B        50-A            SLP              ?
B        50-B            SLP              ?
```

OUTPUT:

```
SKU Cross_Reference Status_Type Product Price
A         A         Active        14.99
A         A1        Active         14.99
A         0-A        SLP           11.99
A         0-B        SLP           11.99
A         0-C        SLP           11.99
B          B         Active        15.99
B         B1        Active         15.99
B        50-A        SLP             0
B        50-B        SLP             0
```

Comment: I think it best that you show your best effort so far and explain what is not happening the way you want it to.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. I tried simple IF statement with IF(AND(both columns from sheet 1,SKU and Type,and then do a return)..but that says formula not valid, so if you can help me with some kind of start point or this can be done with some other statements and not IF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one 'Product Price' in Sheet1!C1 and the other 'Product Price' in Sheet2!D1, put this into Sheet2!D2 and fill down.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:E, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0), MATCH(C2, {"active","","slp"}, 0)+AND(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:B, 2, FALSE)="pd", C2<>"slp"))
```

Comment: @Thanks so much for helping me out.:)... I am getting N/A error. how to overcome that.?.This was something way beyond my Excel expertise.

Comment: If you're getting #N/A errors then there is a problem with your data or your layout. See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/192ENQpeiGmwj4ja71GwcE-haIpWC6nmHz_3qAYz8_1s

Comment: @Jeeped..Thank you so much..really appreciate all your help